# Copy a table from iPython notebook into Word?

Tags: ios, ms-word, ipython

I want to copy a table from iPython notebook into a Word doc. I'm using Word for Mac 2011. The table is a standard pandas output and looks like this:

[image]

If I use Apple+C to copy the table, and then paste it into a Word doc, I get this:

[image]

Surely there must be an easier way?

Creating a table with the same number of rows/columns in Word and then trying to paste the cells there doesn't work either.

I guess I could screenshot the table, but I'd like to include the raw data in the document if possible.

Comment: I'm not familiar with anything in this question except for (Win)Word, but... Can you output the table data in character-delimited format? Either as a file or a string? If yes, that can be inserted/written in/to the document and converted to a table using the Word object model's ConvertToTable method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case (from the Word perspective) is not the table layout - it's the paragraph layout. Each paragraph has a substantial indent on right and left, and more space before/after than you would normally want.

I don't think any of the Paste options (e.g. Paste Special) in Word is going to help, unless you paste as unformatted text, then select the text, convert to a table, then proceed from there.

But, even a simple Word VBA macro such as this one will leave you with something a bit more manageable. (Select a table you copied in, then run the macro). A little bit more work on the code would probably allow you to get most of the formatting you want, most of the time.

```
Sub fixupSelectedTable()
With Selection.Tables(1).Range.ParagraphFormat
  .LeftIndent = 0
  .RightIndent = 0
  .SpaceBefore = 0
  .SpaceAfter = 0
  .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
End With
End Sub
```

If you are more familiar with Applescript, the equivalent looks something like this:

```
-- you may need to fix up the application name
-- (I use this to ensure that the script uses the Open Word 2011 doc
-- and does not try to start Word for Mac 15 (2016))
tell application "/Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Microsoft Word.app"
    tell the paragraph format of the text object of table 1 of the text object of the selection
        set paragraph format left indent to 0
        set paragraph format right indent to 0
        set space before to 0
        set space after to 0
        set line spacing rule to line space single
    end tell
end tell
```